# Keeping track of WebSocket connections

Tags: c#, websocket

I am currently trying out raw WebSockets within a C#-application for learning purposes. I want to be able to store the connections so I can call them from another place in my application. My goal is to build a chat-server which redirects messages to clients and is able to handle as much requests per second as possible. So my biggest concern is speed. Scalability is not.

What is the best way to store WebSocket-connections?

My first thought was using [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary-class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=net-6.0), but I am not sure if that is the right choice.

Comment: I think we need more context for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I see. I have updated my question. Does this provide enough context?

Comment: What would you use as key? By more context I mean _how_ you intend to use the multiple connections, in a general sense.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Oh ok, I intend to use it for a chat application. So I'd reuse connections to forward messages to right client. Users will be assigned a GUID after the handshake, so I thought I'd store WebSocket-classes in an Dictionary<string, WebSocket>.

Comment: I have narrowed my question down to a specific use case